# How to add # to two consecutive lines in one command

Tags: sed

I would like to edit /etc/pacman.conf
In there, there are two lines which I would like to comment:

```
[multilib-testing]  
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

I used sed to comment the first line like this:

```
sudo sed -i ',\[multilib-testing\],s,^,#'
```

which worked, but I would also like to append a # to the next line as well

Is it possible to do both in one command instead of using sed again to search for the newly appended line

```
#[multilib-testing]
```

and then add a # to the next line as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\[multilib-testing\]/!b;N;s/^/#/;s/\n/\n#/' file
```

Add `-i` and possible `sudo` as required.

If the current line doesn't match the regex, skip. Otherwise, pull in the next line with `N`. We then perform the substitution in both places, at beginning of the first line and immediately after the embedded newline.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked and I was also able to use this for another substitution I had  
`#ParallelDownloads = 5`  
where I wanted to remove the # and add ILoveCandy to the next line
`sudo sed -i '/#ParallelDownloads = 5/!b;N;s/^.//;s/\n/\nILoveCandy/' /etc/pacman.conf`

Comment: You should probably merge the two scripts, though then plain `b` will not work. Switch to braces around the commands you want to perform when a specific condition is met, or create a label after the first action with `:label` and branch there with `blabel` instead of the first `b`. The precise syntax will vary slightly between `sed` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak '/\[multilib-testing]/N;s/^\(.*\n\)/#\1#/' input_file
#[multilib-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```